# Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$. Find the number of subsets $A$ of $S$ such that $x \in A$ and $2x \in S \implies 2x \in A$.

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

Let $S=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$. Find the number of subsets $A\subseteq S$ such that $x\in A$ and $2x\in S$ $\implies 2x\in A$.

***My Attempt***
I broke the problem into cases. I made pairs $(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),(4,8),(5,10)$.
If considering these pairs only there are
$$\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{5}=2^5-1=31$$
Considering solely elements of $\{6,7,8,9,10 \}$ there are similarly $31$ subsets.
Now there may be cases where both occur.
$$2^4\binom{5}{1}+2^3\binom{5}{2}+2^2\binom{5}{3}+2^1\binom{5}{4}+2^0\binom{5}{5}=211$$
Clearly answer after summing all and including empty set is $31+31+211+1=274$.
It is not likely to be correct please give a systematic proceeding of solution.

**Edit**: On making an important comment by @Desparado
I would change tuples to $(\pmb1,2,4,8),(\pmb2,4,8),(\pmb3,6),(\pmb4,8),(\pmb5,10),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)$.
Boldface indicates the entry which must be accompanied by the following in that particular tuple in the subset.
Correct answer is 180 given by @lulu and @Desperado in the comments

Comment: I get $360$ mentally (so could have it wrong).  My method:  the least power of $2$ in $A$ is one of $\emptyset,0, 1, 2, 3$ ($5$ choices).  Considering $3$ you get one of $\emptyset, 3, 6$ ($3$ choices) and similarly $\emptyset, 5, 10$ ($3$ choices). then any subset of $\emptyset, 7, 9$ ($8$ choices).  And $5\times 3\times 3 \times 8=360$. I think the approach is good, though I strongly recommend checking the details.

Comment: Not sure what I wrote was clear.  If, say, in the first case you choose $1$ then when we have $1\not \in A$ but $2^1=2\in A$.  Which means that $4,8$ are also in $A$.  My point was that whatever you choose uniquely determines which elements of the given set are in $A$.  For clarity, I probably should have phrased the first choice as a choice between $\{\emptyset, 1, 2, 4, 8\}$... for whatever reason I focussed on the exponent in the power of $2$.

Comment: @lulu, I guess the options for the subsets involving 7 and 9 are just 4, so you have a total of 180 possible subsets A. For the rest it seems fine, nice idea!

Comment: @TechnoFreak What is not working in your approach is that you pick independently  for examplethe pairs (1,2) and (2,4). But taking (1,2) force you to take (2,4) and also (4,8), so they are not independent choices

Comment: @Desperado, Oh, right.  I can't choose the empty set *along with* anything else.  Thanks, good catch.  I'm off by a factor of $2$.

Comment: @Desperado you got some mistake that's absolutely great. Thanks for the correction.Still processing answer though.

Comment: Partition $S$ into the five sets $$\{1,2,4,8\}$$ $$\{3,6\}$$ $$\{5,10\}$$ $$\{7\}$$ $$\{9\}$$ and decide how many elements you want to take from each set.

Answer (score 2):

A subset $A$ of $S$ satisfying your property is exactly the same as a set that satisfies the following properties :

1. If $A$ contains 1, then $A$ contains $1$,$2$,$4$ and $8$ ;
2. If $A$ contains 2, then $A$ contains $2$,$4$ and $8$ ;
3. If $A$ contains 3, then $A$ contains $3$, $6$ ;
4. If $A$ contains 4, then $A$ contains $4$ and $8$ ;
5. If $A$ contains 5, then $A$ contains $5$ and $10$ ;

Five families of numbers appear : $(1,2,4,8)$, $(3,6)$, $(5,10)$, $(7)$ and $(9)$ (two numbers which can or cannot be in $A$ without any consequence on the property).

$A$ is therefore given by exactly 5 **independant** informations, which are the four smallest numbers that $A$ contains in these families (or if it contains none of the numbers of a family).

We have $5$ choices for the first family ($A$ contains no one / $A$ contains only $8$ / $A$ contains $4$ and $8$ / $A$ contains $2,4,8$ / $A$ contains $1,2,4,8$) ; $3$ choices for the 2nd family ; $3$ choices for the 3rd family and 2 choices for each of the last two families ($A$ contains 7 or $A$ does not contain 7). Which gives a total of
$$5 \times 3 \times 3 \times 2 \times 2 = 180 \text{ possibilities}.$$